# Setting Gridview SelectedIndex crashes

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

When I try to set the property it crashes saying the value doesn't fall in range. It works when its -1, but when it changes to 0 it crashes. I'm trying to make the `GridView` item stay selected when the user navigates away from the page then back to it (in a Windows 8 app).

```
listDeckNames.SetValue(GridView.SelectedIndexProperty, (int)Global.selectedDeck);
```

Am I not allowed to do this or is there another solution?

```
<ListView x:Name="listDeckNames"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Height="324" 
          Margin="0" 
          VerticalAlignment="top" 
          Width="663" 
          Background="#FF666666"   
          Canvas.Left="10" 
          SelectionChanged="listDeckNames_SelectionChanged" />
```

I tried switching to a `ListView` but it still crashes.

Comment: Does the listDeckNames have any items?

Comment: Yes, it has two. I set the global variable based on the item that was selected by the user then store it for when the user navigates back to the page.

Comment: Can you paste a larger code sample (it would be useful to know how you are setting the listDeckNames data source, and in which event you are setting the index).